# Set a dataframe as column names for another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

So I have a data frame (called SNPlist) which is of dimensions 1 by 500000 (rows by columns). I want SNP list to be the column names for my dataframe of data (called Data) which is of dimension 100 by 500000. I already tried `colnames(Data) <- SNPlist` but it does not seem to be working. Can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `SNPlist` is a `data.frame`, then you need to point to the first row of it:

```
colnames(Data) <- SNPlist[1, ]
```

If it was a vector, what you'd tried would have worked

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since the question was asked, but I noticed nobody suggested what works for me:
colnames(Data) <- colnames(SNPlist)

Amos

Answer (score 0):

I was having a lot of trouble with this because the usual method (provided above by alexwhan) wasn't getting it done. I eventually got around it by first ripping out a headers `vector` from the old data frame and using the `names` function to slap it on the new one.

```
names(new_DF) <- as.character(apply(old_DF["wanted_header_row", ], 1, paste))
```

Perhaps it's a bit much, but it was the only thing that worked for me.